# MySQL Trigger After Insert Value on Another Table

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, insert

I have a table with a list of my cellphone contacts this is the structure of **contacts** table.

[image]

And the other one is **smartteleco** table.

[image]

The *ContactId* of **smartteleco** table is FOREIGN KEY to the *ContactId* of **contacts**.

I'm creating a trigger that if I *INSERT* a value **into contacts** table and the *ContactNumber1 value **starts with 0918,0919,0920,0921*** it will be stored in the **CellNumber** field of **smartteleco** table.

These are the triggers I've already tried but there is a syntax error and the error is always inside the **IF STATEMENT**.

```
CREATE TRIGGER addSmart
    AFTER INSERT ON contacts
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
             IF(substring(ContactNumber1,1,4) IN (0918,0919,0920,0921) = 1)
                SET CellNumber = substring(ContactNumber1,1,11);
             END IF;
        END



CREATE TRIGGER addSmart
    AFTER INSERT ON contacts
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
             IF(substring(ContactNumber1,1,4) IN (0918,0919,0920,0921) = 1)
                INSERT INTO smartteleco (CellNumber) VALUES (ContactNumber1);
             END IF;
        END



CREATE TRIGGER addSmart
        AFTER INSERT ON contacts
            FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
                 IF(substring(ContactNumber1,1,4) IN (0918,0919,0920,0921) = 1)
                    INSERT INTO smartteleco (NEW.CellNumber) VALUES (NEW.ContactNumber1);
                 END IF;
            END


CREATE TRIGGER addSmart
    AFTER INSERT ON contacts
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
             IF(substring(ContactNumber1,1,4) IN (0918,0919,0920,0921) = 1)
                SET CellNumber = ContactNumber1;
             END IF;
        END



  CREATE TRIGGER addSmart
    AFTER INSERT ON contacts
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
             IF(substring(ContactNumber1,1,4) IN (0918,0919,0920,0921) = 1)
                SET NEW.CellNumber = NEW.ContactNumber1;
             END IF;
        END
```

Comment: Please post the error message

Answer (score 0):

A row trigger cannot directly access the columns of the table to which it is attached. It *can* access the values in the newly-inserted record by using the pseudorecord **`NEW`**. To make your triggers work, just replace the references to `ContactNumber1` with references to `NEW.ContactNumber1`.

You also need to use the correct syntax for your IF structures, which is

```
IF <contition> THEN  --< You need this keyword
  <statement>
END IF;
```

You might also need to cast `ContactNumber1` as `CHAR` to use `substring()` on it.

So the correct trigger syntax should be

```
CREATE TRIGGER addSmart
  AFTER INSERT ON contacts
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF(substring(CAST(NEW.ContactNumber1 AS CHAR(11)), 1, 4) IN ('0918', '0919', '0920' ,'0921'))
  THEN
    INSERT INTO smartteleco (ContactId, CellNumber)
      VALUES (NEW.ContactId, NEW.ContactNumber1);
  END IF;
END
```

EDIT: Syntax corrected. I also discovered that you will need to change the column `ContactNumber1` from `INT(11)` to `CHAR(11)`, which is actually the preferred data type since you will never be performing arithmetic on a phone number.

Comment: Thanks for the info but  there is an error.  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' ' at line 7

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    BEGIN
         IF SUBSTRING(NEW.ContactNumber1,1,4) IN ('0918','0919','0920','0921') THEN
             INSERT INTO smartteleco (CellNumber) VALUES (NEW.ContactNumber1);
         END IF;
    END
```

Comment: It doesn't work it says. 

 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE substring(NEW.ContactNumber1,1,4) IN ('0918','0919','0920','0921')' at line 6